# issue with pandas when launching a python script

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter, xlsx

I'm using Jupyter Notebook to create a graph out of an xlsx file.
the code works and the graph is shown correctly on Jupyter but when i try to launch the script from CLI i get this result :

λ python Untitled.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br/> File "Untitled.py", line 25, in <module><br/> 
 df = pd.read_excel(workbook)<br/> File
 "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 299, in
 wrapper<br/>   return func(*args, **kwargs)<br/> File
 "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 336, in
 read_excel<br/>   io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options,
 engine=engine)<br/> File
 "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1131, in
 __init__<br/>   self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)<br/> File
"C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 24, in
 __init__<br/>   import_optional_dependency("xlrd", extra=err_msg)<br/> File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\_optional.py", line
 109, in import_optional_dependency   raise ImportError(msg) from
 None<br/> ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install
 xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd.
```

**The code is the following :**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

workbook = "sample_scores.xlsx"

df = pd.read_excel(workbook)
print(df.head())

values = df[['Name','Test 1']]
print (values)

ax = values.plot.bar(x='Name', y='Test 1')
plt.show()
```

I installed pandas and matplotlib packages and also verified Python path and everything is set correctly but it seems I'm missing something?

Comment: just install `xlrd` module

Comment: After using  pip install xlrd i had to use  pip install openpyxl  too to make it work .
thanks!

Comment: yes and then pass `engine='openpyxl'` as parameter in `pd.read_excel()` method

Answer (score 1):

```
!pip install xlrd
```

Install xlrd module

Comment: I got this message : 
Your version of xlrd is {xlrd_version}. In xlrd >= 2.0, "
ValueError: Your version of xlrd is 2.0.1. In xlrd >= 2.0, only the xls format is supported. Install openpyxl instead.
i had to do 'pip install openpyxl' after it and now it worked. thanks !

Comment: Updated to modern practices, this should be `%pip install xlrd` (or `openpyxl`). See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the modern `%pip install` & `%conda install` magic commands that insure the installation occurs in the environment backing the underlying kernel. The exclamation point alone doesn't do that, as covered in the top of the paragraph [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez), often causing issues/confusion.